# Call function in dijit / dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm completely new to Dojo and Dijit. I'm trying to fix a bug in a large website, which I'm also new to.

I would like to call a method (closeDropDown) on a DateTextBox. I have read some documents and I thought I understood it well enough, but I just can't get it to work.

In a keyEvent, I'm getting the DateTextBox:

```
dijit.byId(e.srcElement.id)
```

which return an `Object`, according to Chrome console. It seems OK when I inspect it (in the Console also).

As I read in the documentation, http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/byId.html, that should give me the Javascript object. It seems correct.

However, when I try:

```
dijit.byId(e.srcElement.id).closeDropDown(false)
```

I get: `TypeError: Object 2013-01-08 has no method 'closeDropDown'`

I can't see what I'm missing. It must be something fundamental I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: I just tried it on this page http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/form/test_DateTextBox.html   `dijit.byId('local').closeDropDown()` and it works fine. You are using dojo 1.7 correct? Perhaps the e.srcElement isn't correct. What does it print out for the object's declaredClass (`dijit.byId(e.srcElement.id).declaredClass`)? It should be dijit.form.DateTextBox

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem another way, I was able to call another method. Unfortunately I never found out why closeDropDown did not work.